# Simple int to float conversion in c++

Tags: c++, floating-point, int

My function so called "inverzMatrika" returns an int type of variable. I need to convert it to a floating-point number. Any suggestions?

```
float inverz;
inverz = (float)(inverzMatrika(matrika));
```

Comment: Conversions between arithmetic types are implicit. `float inverz = inverzMatrika(matrika);` And that's that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `static_cast`, don't use C style cast

```
float inverz = static_cast<float>(inverzMatrika(matrika));
```

Comment: It still doesn't convert it to a floating-point value. I've tried everything you all suggested. Maybe I forgot to mention that, the value can be also negative, if it's important.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 double inverz;
 inverz=  (double )(inverzMatrika(matrika));
```

Or

```
float inverz = static_cast<float>(inverzMatrika(matrika));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need not to worry about this conversion because it will be implicitly handled by the compiler. We don't lose data on conversion from int to float, hence no explicit type-casting tricks are required here.

Comment: “We don't lose data on conversion from int to float” I think we do. Try converting a 32-bit `int` type's `INT_MAX` to an IEEE 754 binary32 `float`.